# VBA loop to go down a distribution list and send the correct attachment

Tags: excel, vba

I am sure this is something simple the code below works for the first entry in the list but does not loop, I literally cannot figure this out

Can anyone shed any light on correcting this loop, please?

I have tried moving the loop inside the 'With OutMail' section, I have tried a do while loop.

```
Sub Send_Emails()

    Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim path As String
    Dim rows As Integer

    Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Distribution List").UsedRange

    'Row = Sheets("Distribution List").rows.count   

     'Send Email  

    For i = 2 To 20
    With OutMail   
      att = r(i, 2).Value
      em1 = r(i, 3).Value
      em2 = r(i, 4).Value
      path = "\\azfs\YFHPublic\Farms Project\Holds By Area\Holds by Area" & "\" & att

     On Error Resume Next:
       .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@email.com"
       .To = em1
       .Subject = "invoices on hold"
       .Body = "this is a test"
       .Attachments.Add path

       .Display
       .Send
        End With

        OutMail = Nothing
        OutApp = Nothing

        i = i + 1     
    Next i

     '  OutMail = Nothing
     '   OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to `debug.print(i)` to check that it really is not looping? If it is looping, I'd check to see if there is data that you expect in `att`, `em1`, and `em2` - since you have `On Error Resume Next` the function will just skip ahead in case of error.

Comment: You're creating a new mailitem for each person in your list, but you're only working with 1 email you created at the beginning, outside of the loop?  Also, take out the `on error resume next` and build logic to avoid known issues.

Comment: Remove the last 3 lines of your For loop.

Comment: @SJR good catch... the loop itself `for i = start to end` will iterate itself, so adding `i = i+1` will skip every other person in the loop.

Comment: Hi Can anyone figure out the logic for if the attachment is not there to skip it instead of sending an email with no attachement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're trying to make a new email for each person in the loop...

```
Sub Send_Emails()

    Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim OutMail As Object 'REMOVED SET FROM HERE
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim path As String
    Dim rows As Integer

    Set r = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Distribution List").UsedRange

    'Row = Sheets("Distribution List").rows.count   

     'Send Email  

    For i = 2 To 20
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 'MOVED TO CREATE NEW MAILITEM FOR EACH LOOP
        With OutMail   
            'OTHER CODE
```

Comment: @Leighholling look at SJR's comment and my explanation on the main post.  Will be significant.

Comment: i have done this still didnt work, but this and the soloution above is the correct answer

Comment: @Leighholling sorry; that was meant as an additional change, not in lieu of my solution.